# Getting foreach to not split apart the file

Tags: file, unix, foreach, shift

my program is designed to take the first parameters as extension, then the rest of the 
parameters as files to be searched for and, if found, modified by the extension. If not found, it prints an error.

Everything is great until:
    ./chExt.sh 'com' 'king cobra.dat'

where $file splits up the two words into 'king' and 'cobra.dat' then runs them separately. I need it to read as a whole 'king cobra.dat' into $file.

I heard something about using "shift" to get it to read as a whole, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
#!/bin/csh                                                                   \

set ext="$1"
shift

echo the remaining are $*
foreach file ($*)
echo $file
if (-r "$file") then
set newName=`echo "$file" | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".$ext"'/g'`
echo $newName
if ( "$file" == "$newName" ) then
:
else
mv "$file" "$newName"
endif
end
else
echo "$file": No such file
end
endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: Joey, This seems very much like a duplicate to a previous question of yours. As the writer, I think you can 'unpost' your unanswered question, just avoid duplication of effort. I'm glad my answer helped. I do mostly agree that csh is not a good long-term approach for scripting, see the grymoire's write-up. (although due to csh culture at my first job I did it for 8 years!) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Csh has some unique variable modifiers, see [grymoire csh var :q (quote) modifier](http://www.grymoire.com//Unix/Csh.html#toc-uh-92)

For you case, you can do

```
foreach file ($*:q)
echo $file:q
if (-r $file:q) then
set newName=`echo $file:q | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".$ext"'/g'`
echo $newName:q
 .....
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a csh to test this with, you may find putting back some of the dbl-quoted variables is required, or at least workable.

I Hope this helps.